# I am getting an empty byte array as result for an API call which is expected to return a png image

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for making the network call. It was expected to return a png image. But from iOS app I am not able to fetch the image, http response is success but getting an empty byte array. I have tried using Postman and from there I am able to see the image as the response. Following is my code snippet.

```
var imageParams: [String: Any] = [:]
imageParams["pois"] = ["start,-37.811581918854074,144.9472252859507","stop,-37.821561918854074,145.9472252859507", "stop,-37.711581918854074,144.9472252859507","stop,-37.751581918854074,144.9472252859507", "end,-37.941581918854074,144.9472252859507"]

    Alamofire.request("http://192.168.43.210:8086/v1/location/getHsMapImage",
                          method: .post,
                          parameters: imageParams,
                          encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,
                          headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"]).responseString { (response) in
                            switch(response.result) {
                            case .success(_):
                                if let data = response.result.value{
                                    print(response.result.value)
                                }
                                break

                            case .failure(_):
                                print(response.result.error)
                                break

                            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to compare any server logs to see if there's a difference in the requests or responses?

Comment: I have not used Alamofire, but I would use a `print(response)` and see if the key really is "result" and then try `print(response["result"])`.

Comment: try to use REST client to see if your request is correct. POSTMAN is an example of a rest client.